# Make a month data in form of year data in Java

Tags: java

I want to show in console a month e.g. 11 in format YYYY, the format of year, month is the expanded version of the MM.
For example the month 11 should be 0011 in console.

```
String s2 = a.nextToken(); 
String s3 = a.nextToken(); 
int s4 = Integer.parseInt(s1); 
int s5 = Integer.parseInt(s2); 
int s6 = Integer.parseInt(s3);
```

Comment: And what have you tried ?

Comment: And basiccly this is just adding 2 zeros at left

Comment: I extracted these two strings for month and year with stringtokenizer                  
       String s2=a.nextToken();
       String s3=a.nextToken();
        int s4=Integer.parseInt(s1);
        int s5=Integer.parseInt(s2);
        int s6=Integer.parseInt(s3);                                                                                                          and i transform in integers, s5,and s6, how can i add two zeros at the left to the integer s5 representation?

Comment: This is not a try, you're just parsint a string^^

Comment: Is there any specific reason that you're using `StringTokenizer` instead of the easier-to-use `Scanner`?

Comment: no @OlivierGrégoire. I can use Scanner instead StringTokenizer

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use a pattern for it, and add or remove anything you want from it; in your case, add two zeroes before MM

```
String pattern = "yyyy-00MM-dd"; 
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);

String date = simpleDateFormat.format(new Date()); 
System.out.println(date);
```

Comment: Please, for years now, stop answering with Date and SimpleDateFormat that is deprecated. use java.time LocalDate and DateTimeFormatter

Comment: OP has a string as input and not a Date object so apart from using old legacy classes it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: OP edited his question @Joakim Danielson, but I'll keep that in mind azro

Comment: OP never had a Date as input in any version

Answer (score -1):

```
private static int leftPad(int s5, int padLength) {
   String str = ""+s5;
   while(str.length() < padLength) {
     str = 0+str;
   }
   return Integer.parseInt(str);
}
```

> @Alin based on your comment provided above if your concern is about padding zeros above should help
>
> output of above method provides int with zeros padded to left

Comment: This will generate the same output for any date, won't it? And it will output 004 rather than 0005 for May for instance.

Comment: Updated above based on @Alin comment

Comment: You can't return an int if you want the answer prefixed with zeroes.